# Does alpha not work with grease pencil?

Tags: shaders, eevee-render-engine, transparency, grease-pencil, toon-shading

I have used alpha to make the grass transparent but it seems that grease pencil doesn't take this into account as there is no grease pencil where the "original" mesh would have been. I'm not even sure if there is a workaround?[image]